# Getting array values echoed instead of the word 'array'

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

When I do the foreach loop for the print_r output I can succesfully output $key but when outputting $cats the output is 'array'. What index do I need to pass to the varibale $cats[??]. Do I need another foreach loop in View or do I need to reorganize the array in controller? (which I tried both without success). As you can tell I am not the master in programming. Thanks for your patience and any direction!

View:

```
<?php foreach($categories_sorted as $key => $cats) : ?>
    <div class="box_container">
        <div class="box_head"><?= $key; ?></div>
        <div class="box_body"><?= $cats; ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Print_r:

```
Array
(
[Things to Do] => Array
    (
        [0] => Activities and  Attractions
        [1] => Castles
        [2] => Golf
        [3] => Islands and Beaches
        [4] => Kids and Family
        [5] => Landmarks and Architecture
        [6] => Museums and Galleries
        [7] => Nightlife
        [8] => Parks and Gardens
        [9] => Shopping
        [10] => Sports and Outdoor
        [11] => Tours Tracks and Cruises
        [12] => Tracks and Trails
        [13] => Wellness
    )

[Transportation] => Array
    (
        [0] => Airport Transfers
        [1] => Car Leasing
        [2] => Flights
        [3] => Public Transport
        [4] => Taxis
        [5] => Transport Lift Ride
        [6] => Vehicle Rental
        [7] => Vehicle Sales
    )
)
```

Controller:

```
function categories(){
    $this->load->model('array_model');
    $category_row = $this->array_model->get_categories_all();


    $arr_maincats = array();
    foreach($category_row as $row){
        if(!isset($arr_maincats[$row['category']]))
            $maincats = $row['maincategory'];
            $arr_maincats[$maincats][] = $row['category'];
    }

    $data['categories_sorted'] = $arr_maincats;
    $this->load->view('array_view', $data);
```

Comment: Try with var_export($cats, true);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, as you suggest, use a foreach within the existing loop to display all of the `$cat` options:

```
<?php foreach($categories_sorted as $key => $cats) : ?>
    <div class="box_container">
        <div class="box_head"><?= $key; ?></div>
        <div class="box_body">
        <?php foreach($cats as $item) { echo $item; } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Alternatively you could "collapse" the `$cats` array into a single string using join or [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and output that:

```
<?php foreach($categories_sorted as $key => $cats) : ?>
    <div class="box_container">
        <div class="box_head"><?= $key; ?></div>
        <div class="box_body">
        <?php echo implode(', ', $cats); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

(Here I've chosen to add a `,` between each $cats item.

Comment: both options work perfectly. Second option is wonderful. Best thanks for that! Ill accept answer shortly...

Answer (score 2):

As it can be seen from your print_r, you have Array containing arrays, so you need to loop through the contained arrays  too. For more understanding I will add a declaration of such array below:

```
<?php
$categories_sorted = array(
    'Things to Do' => array(
        0   =>  'Activities and  Attractions',
        1   =>  'Castles',
        2   =>  'Golf',
        3   =>  'Islands and Beaches'
    ),
    'Transportation' => array(
        0   =>  'Airport Transfers',
        1   =>  'Car Leasing',
        2   =>  'Flights',
        3   =>  'Public Transport'
    )
);
?>

<?php foreach($categories_sorted as $key => $cats) : ?>
<div class="box_container">
        <div class="box_head"><?= $key; ?></div>
        <?php foreach($cats as $k => $cat): ?>
        <div class="box_body"><?= $cat; ?></div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Depends on the needs you have, you should consider where to put the second foreach, if you need to create `<div class="box_body">` or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `<?=`'s functionaltly is same as  `echo` so when you try to `<?= $cat` it gives `array`. It would be better if you use `print_r($cat)`

Comment: Though your answer is correct regarding the results of `echo $arry` compared to `print_r($arry)` (where `$arry` is obviously of type array) I somehow doubt, that `print_r`-ing the array for purposes other than "debugging" is a proper solution for the OP's problem.

Comment: Aagree..I was not quite certain to what the OP wants to do with $cat and was waiting for his comment..sadly he didn't .

Answer (score 1):

Check out `var_dump` and its related functions in the "see also" section:

[PHP.net Resource Guide](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)